# How do I echo a row as a class?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

How do I echo a row as a `class`?

I'm trying to echo a class to a bootstrap icon, I tried everything, but can't seem to get it working.

I want my script to add the smiley class from my `MySQL` to a `<i class=""></i>` class. To insert a sad/happy smile depending on the search..

I attached a screenshot of the `MySQL`..

```
include_once ('mad-forbind.php');

if(isset($_GET['mad'])){
    $mad =  trim($_GET['mad']) ;
$mad = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $mad);

$query = "select navn,kalorier,fedt, kul, protein, smiley from vare where navn like '%$mad%' or kalorier like '%$mad%'";

//echo $query;
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if($result){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<p> <b>'.$row['navn'].'</b> **My smiley here** Kalorier: '.$row['kalorier'].' Fedt: '.$row['fedt'].' Kulhydrater: '.$row['kul'].' Protein: '.$row['protein'].' </p>'   ;
    }
    }else {
        echo 'Vi kunne desværre ikke finde:"'.$_GET['mad'].'"';
    }

}
}else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
}
```

A screenshot of my `MySQL`:

[image]

Comment: where is the html code where you want to add these font-awsome classes  that you have stored in database

Comment: `<i class='" . $row['smiley'] . "'></i> ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your echo statement // Assumed that you have extracted the smiley data in .$row['smiley']

```
echo '<p> <b>'.$row['navn'].'</b> **My smiley here** Kalorier: '.$row['kalorier'].' Fedt: '.$row['fedt'].' Kulhydrater: '.$row['kul'].' Protein: '.$row['protein'].' <i class=\"'.$row['smiley'].'\"></i></p>'   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you find the inline comments

```
include_once ('mad-forbind.php');

if(isset($_GET['mad']))
{
    $mad =  trim($_GET['mad']) ;
    $mad = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $mad);

    $query = "select navn,kalorier,fedt, kul, protein, smiley from vare where navn like '%$mad%' or kalorier like '%$mad%'";

    //echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    if($result)
    {
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0)
        {
            //create table here
            $table = '<table>';
            $table .= '<tr>';
            $table .= '<th>navn</th>';
            $table .= '<th>kalorier</th>';
            $table .= '<th>kul</th>';
            $table .= '<th>fedt</th>';
            $table .= '<th>protein</th>';
            $table .= '<th>smiley</th>';
            $table .= '</tr>';

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
              {
                $table .= '<tr>';
                $table .= '<td>'.$row['navn'].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td>'.$row['kalorier'].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td>'.$row['kul'].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td>'.$row['fedt'].'</td>';
                $table .= '<td>'.$row['protein'].'</td>';           
                $table .= '<td>'.$row['smiley'].'</td>';
                $table .= '</tr>';
              }

            $table .= '</table>';

            //display the table here
            echo $table;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'Vi kunne desværre ikke finde:"'.$_GET['mad'].'"';
        }

    }
}
else 
{
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "color: red";
echo "<html><head><style>
p.intro {
    ".$a."
}
</style></head>
      <body><p class='intro'>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p></body></html>";
```